# Adding certificate for heroku app

Tags: ssl, heroku, dnsimple

After I have followed the instructions on heroku to add a certificate from DNSimple, I still have this error when I try to access the website:

www.web.com uses an invalid security certificate.

The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided.
The certificate is only valid for the following names:
  *.herokuapp.com , herokuapp.com

(Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)

So, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your hostname points to the Heroku generic app endpoint.

```
➜  ~  dig www.dcaclab.com +short
web.herokuapp.com.
us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com.
54.243.166.168
```

The `CNAME` should [point to the Heroku SSL endpoint](http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/ssl-certificate-with-heroku).

Comment: Doesn't work for me at the moment. I already have a CNAME record points to the Heorku SSL Endpoint but `dig` still shows the generic endpoint. It's really confusing.

Comment: It means the DNS configuration is incorrect, or the DNS lookup is cached on your side